# My "push array" function is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a final fantasy ATB battle system and i'm currently trying to implement a "haste feature". Instead of waiting 6 seconds before you can act, the haste will let you act within 3 seconds. I basically setup a *user* object which has a *status* property that is a empty array. When the haste button is executed, I "push" the word "haste" into the array. Then I make a statement that says if I have the "haste status", then I will have my timer act on 3 seconds over 6. The problem i'm running into is that if I have anything other than "haste" into the array, this effect breaks. For example, if I hit the haste button 3 times, this will push the "haste" word into the array 3 times, which is not a issue as I can remove it later. The issue i'm having is that if ANYTHING other than just a single "haste" is in the array, this effect does not work, which is not what I want because in the future i'm going to use it to push in other status effects. How can I tell my code that even if other array items are in my array, to still execute the effect?

```
function hasteButton() {
    atbReset()
    user.status.push("haste");
    console.log(user.status);
};

var user = {
    status: []
};

function timeBar(el, color) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(el);
    if (user.status == "haste") {
        elem.style.transition = "width 3.0s, linear 0s";
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            boxLight()
        }, 2800);
    } else {
        elem.style.transition = "width 6.0s, linear 0s";
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            boxLight()
        }, 5800);
    }
}
```

Comment: Further to what's already been said below, Javascript is helpfully converting your array to a string "haste" when there is one and only one element in the array.  If you use === instead of == the conversion won't happen and things won't work sometimes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a mistake in your code: you use an array but you check it as a string; change

```
if (user.status == "haste") {
```

with

```
if (user.status.indexOf("haste") != -1) {
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer as it worked perfectly and fits what I want to do in the future with my game. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want to set a haste property, not push an item in the array.  That way you can just check the property directly regardless of what else is in the array and the haste setting will be independent of the other things in the array.  An array is for an ordered collection, but the `haste` status seems to just be Boolean status regardless of what is in the array so it doesn't seem to belong in the array.

You can just make the haste `setting` a property of the status array like this:

```
function hasteButton() {
    atbReset()
    user.status.haste = true;
    console.log(user.status);
};

var user = {
    status: []
};

function timeBar(el, color) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(el);
    if (user.status.haste) {
        elem.style.transition = "width 3.0s, linear 0s";
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            boxLight()
        }, 2800);
    } else {
        elem.style.transition = "width 6.0s, linear 0s";
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            boxLight()
        }, 5800);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have: `user.status`. This call will return an array, you would need to access it's elements in one way or another.

I would recommend doing something like:

```
if (user.status.indexOf('haste') >= 0) {
  // do action
}
```

The `indexOf` method on arrays returns -1 if the element you ask it to find the index of isn't in the array.

Comment: `> 0` will not find the 0-th position (e.g. `["haste"]`).